# SQL count in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query that creates a label in a cab file for a shopping company. I want to include the amount of packages in an order, some have multiple.

Each returns line in my select query has an I’d and contains a package but I need to count them.

So I have:

```
Name  Email   Weight Price ID
Joe B J@.com    10   12.5. 1
Joe B J@.com    10   12.5. 1
Joe C JC@.com   10   14.5. 2
```

How can I count the ID’s to return a column called pieces and in this example it would be 2 for ID 1 and 1 for ID 2

Thanks

James

```
    enter code here
```

Select 
    'WPX' As 'Product Code',
     delivery_header.dh_datetime As  'Shipment Date',
     'G' As 'Shipment Type',
     order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_email As 'Receiver Email Address',
  variant_detail.vad_weight As 'Shipment Weight in KG',

(lots of other fields....)

```
delivery_header.dh_number As 'Shippers Reference',
(SELECT Count(*)
FROM  delivery_header
WHERE
 dh_number = OU.dh_number
) As 'Number of Pieces',







From delivery_line_item Inner Join
  delivery_header On delivery_header.dh_id = delivery_line_item.dli_dh_id
  Inner Join
  order_line_item On delivery_line_item.dli_oli_id = order_line_item.oli_id
  Inner Join
  variant_detail On variant_detail.vad_id = order_line_item.oli_vad_id
  Inner Join
  order_header On order_header.oh_id = order_line_item.oli_oh_id Inner Join
  stock_location On stock_location.sl_id = order_line_item.oli_sl_id Inner Join
  customer_detail On customer_detail.cd_id = order_header.oh_cd_id Inner Join
  order_header_detail On order_header.oh_id = order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id
  Left Join
  order_header_analysis On order_header.oh_id = order_header_analysis.oha_oh_id
  Left Join
  order_customer_analysis On order_header.oh_id =
    order_customer_analysis.oca_oh_id Left Join
  order_delivery_analysis On order_header.oh_id =
    order_delivery_analysis.oda_oh_id Left Join
  order_line_analysis On order_line_item.oli_id = order_line_analysis.ola_oli_id
  Left Join
  order_line_product_analysis On order_line_item.oli_id =
    order_line_product_analysis.olpa_oli_id Left Join
  order_line_variant_analysis On order_line_item.oli_id =
    order_line_variant_analysis.olva_oli_id Inner Join
  product_detail On product_detail.pd_id = variant_detail.vad_pd_id Inner Join
  delivery_method On delivery_method.dm_id = order_header_detail.ohd_dm_id
  Inner Join
  delivery_method [Delivery Method] On [Delivery Method].dm_id =
    order_header_detail.ohd_dm_id Inner Join
  currency On currency.c_id = order_header.oh_c_id And currency.c_id =
    delivery_method.dm_c_id And currency.c_id = [Delivery Method].dm_c_id
Where 
  delivery_header.dh_number  IN (199364,199363,199362,199360)

Order By delivery_header.dh_number
```

Comment: Is that table data or the current result? Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name *SQL is a standard

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and the expected output based on your sample data. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @foxdie: yes it's a standard, but no DBMS fully implements the standard and some deviate substantially from it or only support a very limited subset of the functionality.

Comment: This is the result, sorry for not specifying that.  What I have so far is just a select query in SQL server. I have tried the COUNT function with CASE but it returns the same result on each line. I want to see the result above but with a new column containing a count of the total amount of occurrences of each ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as count FROM tbl GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that, you are looking for output like

```
Name  Email   Weight Price ID Pieces 
Joe B J@.com    10   12.5. 1  2
Joe B J@.com    10   12.5. 1  2
Joe C JC@.com   10   14.5. 2  1
```

Using following query you should get the desired output in most of the DBMS.

```
   SELECT NAME, 
       EMAIL, 
       WEIGHT, 
       PRICE, 
       ID, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> 
        WHERE  ID= OU.ID) AS Pieces  
FROM   <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> OU
```

Similar Query for MS SQL Server can be

```
SELECT NAME, EMAIL,WEIGHT , Price, ID,CT.Pieces 
FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> OU
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS Pieces FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> IU WHERE OU.ID=IU.ID
 )CT
```

Comment: A window function would be a **lot** more efficient

Comment: P_K that’s exactly what I want as far as output!

Comment: I get an error An error occured: The multi-part identifier "OU.dh_number" could not be bound.

Comment: I have included my SQL above in my initial question.

Comment: @J.Pett OU is just a alias name I have given to the main table. In your case I think you need to change OU with delivery_header and it should work

Comment: @P_K thanks for that, not sure what I was thinking there. I added the table name and no ,longer get an error but it seems to be counting the total amount of ID's in the table. I got a result of 199236, which I guess is every ID in my DB.

Comment: I suggest you use alias name to each table and use the alias name of outer table inside your select statment. It will work